# How can I change values froma vector with a previous condition?

Tags: r

I have a logical vector
`vector1 <- c(F,F,T,F,F)`
and I want to create a `vector2` with the same values as `vector1` but when `vector1[i] == TRUE` `vector2[i-1], vector2[i] and vector2[i+1]` has to be also `TRUE`. 
What is the best way to do this? the ideal would be to create a function also since I will have to this for many other vectors...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way using boolean comparison is:

```
c(vector1[-1], FALSE) | vector1 | c(FALSE, vector1[-length(vector1)])
```

Value is `TRUE` at a position if the preceding is `TRUE`, or the position is `TRUE` or the next position is `TRUE`. First and last values are boundaries and have no preceding or next values, that is why positions are completed by `FALSE`.

For more than one position, here two:

```
lag <- 2
c(vector1[-(1:lag)], rep(FALSE, lag)) | vector1 | c(rep(FALSE, lag), vector1[-(length(vector1)-lag+1:length(vector1))])
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: I cant wrap my head around this simplicity... Can you please go through on what is happening in this line of code?

Comment: Is it possible to go backwards and forward more than one position with this type of code?

Answer (score 3):

You can also try `dplyr`:

```
case_when(lead(vector1) ~ TRUE,
          lag(vector1) ~ TRUE,
          TRUE ~ vector1)

[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: It is possible to go behind and after more than one position? what should i put in the lead and lag if I want to go 2 backwards and 2 positions after?

Comment: It is possible. Both `lag()` and `lead` has an `n` parameter: a positive integer of length 1, giving the number of positions to lead or lag by.

Answer (score 2):

You can do :

```
#Copy vector1 elements
vector2 <- vector1
#Get indices where vector has TRUE elements
inds <- which(vector2)
#Get +1 and -1 position of each TRUE value
inds1 <- unique(c(inds + 1, inds -  1))
#Remove values which are out of range
inds1 <- inds1[inds1 <= length(vector2) & inds1 >= 1]
#Assign TRUE values
vector2[inds1] <- TRUE
vector2
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Add one element to vector if `TRUE` in last position